# How to modify a job on the fly in APScheduler?

Tags: python, scheduler, apscheduler, on-the-fly

I have a periodic job. Since its upgrades are needed and I do not want to stop the main code, I wish I could modify/update the job on the fly. I'll demonstrate by simple example.

Main script:

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
from my_job_func import my_job

if __name__ == '__main__':

    scheduler = BlockingScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(my_job, 'interval', seconds=3)

    try:
        scheduler.start()
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        pass
```

job to be modified on-the-fly in file my_job_func.py:

```
def my_job():

    print('Make some changes!!')
```

So, is it somehow possible to modify or update my_job() on-the-fly without stopping the main script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```py
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
from apscheduler.triggers.interval import IntervalTrigger

from my_job_func import my_job

def observer(job):
    # you can either reschedule the job
    job.reschedule(...)

    # or modify it
    changes = get_update()  # get update from configuration
    job.modify(**changes)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    scheduler = BlockingScheduler()
    my_job_id = scheduler.add_job(my_job, 'interval', seconds=3)

    scheduler.add_job(observer, IntervalTrigger(minutes=5), args=(my_job_id,), name="observer")
    scheduler.start()
```

You can add a separate observer job help modifying `my_job` on the fly.

Note that the change may not take effect in no time. You can adjust the observer job's interval to fit your need.