# How to change job parameters in telegram app using telegram.ext functionality?

Tags: python, scheduler, python-telegram-bot, job-queue

I'm trying to understand how jobs working in telegram.ext module and writing small bot for this:
user should be able to set time for reminder and change this time.
I created a job using job_queue.run_daily:
`context.job_queue.run_daily(alarm, chat_id=update.effective_user.id, time=time2check, data="smth").enabled = True`
How can I change time for a job using build-in functions of telegram.ext?
I found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64874247/20238505, but it is consider using plain APScheduler. Since JobQueue is 'convenience wrapper for the APScheduler library', maybe it has some convenient functions to change job parameters, such as time?

I didn't find an answer in docs (https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.ext.jobqueue.html), but maybe I don't understand something right.
First thought in solving this task was to recreate job with new 'time' argument, but it seems a little redundant for me.

UPD:
Summarizing answer provided by CallMeStag and my research (I’m using cron trigger in my program):
One should use APScheduler functionality to change job parameters. One can reschedule the job which was found using `context.job_queue.get_jobs_by_name(jobname)` with something like:
`job.job.reschedule(trigger='cron', hour=hour, minute=minute, day_of_week=day_of_week, timezone=tz)`
Need to mention that if we want to change only one parameter we still have to provide all others parameters otherwise APScheduler will set them to default [values](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/3.x/modules/triggers/cron.html#introduction). For example, if I had a job which executes at 12:00 every sunday, and I change only hour parameter  to 9, then job will execute on every day of the week.
So we need to get values of parameters which have to be preserved.
`job.trigger` class has all we need to achieve that. Tuple of parameters' names (`.FIELD_NAMES = ('year', 'month', 'day', 'week', 'day_of_week', 'hour', 'minute', 'second')`) and list of classes with those names which store current settings for each parameter (`.fields`). So to get day of week settings we can do:
`day_of_week = job.trigger.fields[job.trigger.FIELD_NAMES.index('day_of_week')]`
Timezone can be read directly from `job.trigger.timezone`.

I hope this would save some time for other newbies in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return value of [`run_daily`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.ext.jobqueue.html#telegram.ext.JobQueue.run_daily) is an instance of the [`telegram.ext.Job`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.ext.job.html#telegram.ext.Job) class, which can be understood as wrepper for the [`apscheduler.job.Job`](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/3.x/modules/job.html#apscheduler.job.Job). More precisely, the underlying APScheduler job is available as [`Job.job`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.ext.job.html#telegram.ext.Job.job). Combined with [How to modify a job on the fly in APScheduler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60465547) that you already cited, this should get you started :)

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintaner of `python-telegram-bot`.